# XML attribute manipulation

Tags: xml

I want to manipulate some of the XML attributes (WSCC, WS etc) in below sample XML.
I have millions of lines in this XML, repeating in same manner.
Any pointer to convert this data in meaningful tabular form will be highly favorable.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<ns0:IDS xmlns:ns0="VPF">
    <ns0:FES>
        <ns0:FE Code="Comp:1:1" Type="PFE">
          <ns0:FM Code="1" Type="AECFM" />
          <ns0:DN Code="Comp:1" Type="AECFMS" />
          <ns0:Main>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="IC">FALSE</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="OA">1</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="PF">WB</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="WSCC">91040</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="WSUT">CC</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="WS">1.342</ns0:Sub>
          </ns0:Main>
        </ns0:FE>
        <ns0:FE Code="Comp:1:1" Type="PFE">
          <ns0:FM Code="1" Type="AECFM" />
          <ns0:DN Code="Comp:1" Type="AECFMS" />
          <ns0:Main>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="IC">FALSE</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="PF">WB</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="WSCC">111242</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="WSUT">CC</ns0:Sub>
            <ns0:Sub Attribute="WS">3.897</ns0:Sub>
          </ns0:Main>
        </ns0:FE>
    </ns0:FES>
</ns0:IDS>
```

Comment: I would argue that it already is in a meaningful tabular form. If you don't agree, then you need to tell us what form you want it in.

Comment: Thanks Michael for taking time out to see at my query.
I was wondering if need to present this data in two by two table (May be in Excel sheet how should I present).
I could manipulable the the values.
is it possible that when I write the amended XML to new XML, I can retain the heading (" <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>")

Comment: I think you need to provide us with a concrete description of the output you want to produce. Retaining an XML declaration is the least of the problems.

Comment: Michael, from given set of data if I need to store in Excel sheet, what would be the best way to save in tabular format, Even I am not sure how many columns and rows would be there and what should be the column names and values in that excel sheet.

I was looking for any pointer if I can get to represent this data in excel sheet with proper format (long or wide) which make sense and easy to read and process.

Comment: Sorry, this site is for coding help, it's not designed for discussing requirements and application design. You might find people prepared to engage in that discussion on the xsl-list at mulberrytech.com.

Comment: Thanks for the Pointer Michael!!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the python code which I used to manipulate the WS and WSCC values and write back to to XML docs.
Since I wrote this code in jupyter notebook and downloaded as py file, it is showing cell numbers also.

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[53]:


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


# In[54]:


tree = ET.parse('test.xml')


# In[55]:


root = tree.getroot()
print(root)


# In[56]:


for child in root:
    print(child.tag,child.attrib)


# In[57]:


[elem.tag for elem in root.iter()]


# In[58]:


for attri in root.iter('{VPF}Sub'):
    print(attri.attrib)


# In[59]:


for wb in root.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WS']"):
    print(wb.attrib)


# In[60]:


# check the original value of WS
root.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WS']")[0].text


# In[61]:


## Doubling the WS in entire XML sheet
for i in tree.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WS']"):
    i.text = str(float(i.text)*2)


# In[62]:


# check the changed value of WS
root.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WS']")[0].text


# In[63]:


# check the original value of wSCC
root.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WSCC']")[0].text


# In[64]:


## finding the 'WSCC' in entire XML sheet
for wb in root.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WSCC']"):
    print(wb.attrib)


# In[65]:


# check the original value of WSCC
root.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WSCC']")[0].text


# In[66]:


## Doubling the WSCC in entire XML sheet
for i in tree.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WSCC']"):
    i.text = str(float(i.text)*2)


# In[67]:


# check the Changed value of WSCC
root.findall(".//{VPF}Sub[@Attribute='WSCC']")[0].text


# In[48]:


# Write out the tree to the file again
tree.write("updated.xml")
```